# React - responsive app - better to hide element in component via CSS or not render it

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm currently working on a React.js-based app. Lets say we have a `Header` component in React with a small logo component inside it that should only be displayed at mobile resolution levels. I'm passing an `isMobile` prop from the parent component. This prop is based on:

```
const mql = global.matchMedia(`(min-width: 768px)`);
mql.addListener(() => this._mediaQueryChanged());
this.setState({
  mql: mql,
  isMobile: !mql.matches
});

_mediaQueryChanged() {
  this.setState({
    isMobile: !this.state.mql.matches
  });
}


<Header isMobile={this.state.isMobile} />
```

And in `Header`:

```
render() {
  const {isMobile} = this.props;
  const containerClass = classNames('header-component', {
    'is-mobile': isMobile
  });
  return (
    <header className={containerClass}>
      {
        isMobile && 
        (
          <section className="mobile-header">
            <Button className="toggle-menu" onClick={() => this._toggleMenu()}>
              <Icon name="menu" />
            </Button>
            <Logo className="header-logo" />
          </section>
        )
      }
      <span>login</span>
    </header>
  );
}
```

and if `mql` matches then it is not mobile. My question is: should I pass this param and re-render the component every time we change Media queries? During re-render hide/show logo component? Or just use CSS to show/hide it and the component will be mounted there all the time. No re-renders tho.

Thoughts?

Comment: I would probably go with a CSS media query because re-rendering over changes in viewport sizes might be expensive, especially if it's constantly changing. Also that's exactly what media queries are for... to change/show/hide appearances based on the size of the viewport.

Answer (score 4):

I agree this may be a job for just CSS.

```
.header-class .logo {
  display:none;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .header-class .logo {
      display:block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on what you're trying to achieve. If you have universal rendering with critical path CSS extraction and trying to shave milliseconds go for the react-only solution. Otherwise css-only solution will do but equally as well as the react-only solution because you're **probably** re-rendering already. That sneaky `isMobile` has just triggered a render somewhere else in your codebase (or will in the future); plus, you've just lost the extensibility of that react offers.